# Dropping a TABLESPACE and USER when table LOCKS are disabled

Tags: oracle

Below are the statements that I run to remove and recreate a USER and TABLESPACE on my local machine in oracle.

```
DROP TABLESPACE X INCLUDING CONTENTS AND DATAFILES ;
DROP USER X CASCADE;
CREATE TABLESPACE X DATAFILE '$ORACLE_PATH/X.dbf' SIZE 128M AUTOEXTEND ON EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;
CREATE USER X IDENTIFIED BY xxxxxxx DEFAULT TABLESPACE X TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp;
GRANT exp_full_database TO X;
GRANT CONNECT,RESOURCE,DBA TO X;
```

We recently added a condition to disable the lock on a table in this TABLESPACE and the above DROP command now issues:

```
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00069: cannot acquire lock -- table locks disabled for TABLE
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
```

Does anyone know of a way to DROP the USER and TABLESPACE without enabling the LOCKs or a better method to recreate a local TABLESPACE and USER with locks disabled?

Cheers

Comment: What method did you use to disable the lock on this tablespace?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name DISABLE TABLE LOCK;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the [DISABLE TABLE LOCK](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_3001.htm#i2056917) command is to prevent DDL. If you could drop the table without re-enabling the table lock first that would be a bug to me.

In your case you will have to enable table locks with a script such as this one:

```
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT owner, table_name
                FROM all_tables
               WHERE tablespace_name = :x
                 AND table_lock = 'DISABLED') LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE "' || cc.owner || '"."' || 
                         cc.table_name || '" ENABLE TABLE LOCK';
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Unfortunately it may take a very long time to execute or even [fail unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5579735/119634):

> **Caution**: Oracle Database waits until
>   active DML transactions in the
>   database have completed before locking
>   the table. Sometimes the resulting
>   delay is considerable.

Comment: Cheers for the feedback @Vincent, I was just unsure whether I needed to do this before recreating a tablespace and user everytime.  I already have a script to run for ownership issues so will amend to use this as well.